# ProgressDiaglog (Status Dialog) in Fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, progressdialog

I am currently trying to create an application for a gym where it allows the user to click a button pertaining to the gym classes to book the class. The classes and the button are in a list view and i am trying to send an email at the click of the button, However this process involves a progress dialog and i am currently using a fragment activity and it seems to not work fragment activities so i get an error.

Here is the code for my SendMailTask`

```
public class SendMailTask extends AsyncTask {
        private ProgressDialog statusDialog;
        private Fragment sendMailActivity;

        public SendMailTask(Fragment activity) {
            sendMailActivity = activity;
        }
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            statusDialog = new ProgressDialog(sendMailActivity);//getting error here under "sendMailActivity"
            statusDialog.setMessage("Getting ready...");
            statusDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            statusDialog.setCancelable(false);
            statusDialog.show();
        }
```

Comment: what error are you getting? have you tried using fragment's activity instead of fragment? `statusDialog = new ProgressDialog(sendMailActivity.getActivity())`